# Why can I not install openj with `apt-get install openj`?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have this error: `dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem`.

How to fixed it?

Comment: Have you tried to run : `sudo dpkg --configure -a` ?

Comment: As it is saying, run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: But someone knows what this command is doing?

Comment: from the man page `--configure package...|-a|--pending:
    Reconfigure an unpacked package. If -a or --pending is given instead of package, all unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured`